# Safari not centering elements with css

Tags: html, css, safari

For all other browsers my css works for centering any element in the page, but not for safari (testing the page on safari 5.1.7 for windows),
it just put the elements to the left like no style has been applied to them.
my css:

```
    .centered {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;     
    }
```

how looks like on safari:

```
|stuff                         |  
|text                          |
|more stuff                    |
```

things i have tried:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

```
 display:inline-block;
```

more code:

```
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Flexbox is not supported by Safari 5 without prefixes - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, but my original code does work with newer version of safari?

Comment: Your question is about Safari 5 right? Then you need to use the older syntax and prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Safari 5.1.7 is old; you shouldn't have to target it specifically any more. If people are still using it, that's their own fault; there are plenty of other choices in browsers!

That said, it looks like you didn't try `text-align: center`, which would have been the solution.

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.centered > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px dotted green; /* for debugging purposes */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div>
    stuff<br>
    text<br>
    more stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

(You didn't say what your HTML looks like, but I'm assuming it's a bit like this.)

Tested in Safari 5.1.7, IE8, FF3.6 and Chromium 20.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, I used the good old legacy HTML
`<center>` tag.